# how to cross compile tensorflow lite for arm64(linux) by using bazel

Tags: tensorflow, build, cross-compiling, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to build the tensorflow lite for 'arm64-v8a' with linux on an amd64 with linux.I follow the [guide](https://tensorflow.google.cn/lite/guide/build_arm64) to build the library libtensorflow-lite.a.but i found there remains a long tail of TensorFlow ops that are not yet natively supported by TensorFlow Lite,so i want Select TensorFlow operators to use in TensorFlow Lite. from the [guide](https://tensorflow.google.cn/lite/guide/ops_select#c) i should Recompile the library, I use the command `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so --cpu=arm64-v8a`, I got the following error:

```
/home/wang/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wang/c72f4772665ac4cb0690414b07635968/external/local_config_cc/BUILD:45:1: in cc_toolchain_suite rule @local_config_cc//:toolchain: cc_toolchain_suite '@local_config_cc//:toolchain' does not contain a toolchain for cpu 'arm64-v8a'
```

I'm new to bazel and cannot find a detailed walkthrough.what should i do?

Comment: need written the BUILD file ,follow the guide https://github.com/xifengcun/tensorflow-aarch64-crossbuild

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? Can you provide the commands for step 1?

Answer (score 0):

my tensorflow-lite build command was this, and it completed with no error:

```
bazel build -c opt --fat_apk_cpu=arm64-v8a \
  --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
  //tensorflow/lite/java:tensorflow-lite
```

since the error references the toolchain, may need to check your java NDK installation. the toolchains are in a subdir:

```
$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/ndk/someversionnumber/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
```